# Where to ask question about alternative Android Markets in South Korea?

Tags: discussion, questions, android, marketing

I have a question about **Android App markets**.

- It is not programming-related, so I would say it is **not for SO**.
- On the other hand, it is of interest to SO more than any other other SE site I know.

Should I post it on SO or not? Any better place?

---

*Full question for reference:

My free open source Android app is very popular in Japan, China, Taiwan, but **not** in Korea, despite Korea being the second biggest Android apps consumer overall. Where do Korean people get their apps? Is there a popular alternative market, like "Docomo Market" in Japan, where I should register my app?*

Comment: This would be a great fit for the proposed App Store site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores , but I don't know if there's that much momentum behind the proposal.

Comment: @Brad: Thanks a lot! That would be the perfect place indeed.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should post the question on http://android.stackexchange.com as @Bart suggests or alternatively on http://programmers.stackexchange.com (from [programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#questions): "This can include topics such as: Freelancing and business concerns").

Comment: I got seriously downvoted last time I asked a localized marketing-related question on Programmers http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89998 . Thanks for the answer! I asked there: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12137

Comment: Both of my Android Market-related questions at Android Enthusiasts have been downvoted and closed as off-topic.